# I have problem with html audio element. It works on firefox, but not on any other browser

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

```
<audio controls
 src="ff.ogg">
</audio>
```

i have this. It plays just fine on Firefox, but with other browsers, when you press play. nothing happens. Except when you mute the audio then the timebar starts scrolling. Any ideas?
I tried Edge and Opera. both doing same things. Its just Firefox that plays its correctly.

Comment: You should provide several different file formats as each browser may only handle certain ones.

Comment: I tried ogg, mp3. All works with firefox, but none else. wondering if theres like some bitrate limitations or something else weird with other browsers. googling did nothing

Comment: This [MDN article about cross-browser audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/Cross-browser_audio_basics) might be a good reference for you. This outlines typical gotchas and syntax examples, as well as audio codec support across browsers.

Comment: Well according to that all browsers pretty much supports mp3. There is something other skechy going on.

Comment: Are you testing from a real web server (i.e., requesting the page via an http:// URL?

Comment: Yes i have real linux server with apache. http://henkka.sytes.net/Nettisivu/ff.html Stupid learning project, but hate that it doesnt work on other browsers